# Maven não carrega todas as classes do WebService correios wsdl

Tags: java-ee

Boa tarde!

Pessoal,

Estou tentado Usar um web service dos correios wsdl para poder fazer a busca do endereço a partir do cep, e para baixar as classes estou fazendo uso do maven, o que me parace que funciona direitinho ele me traz as classe porem estão faltando algumas.

segue a parte do código que estou usando no meu pom.xml para realizar essa tarefa.

```
 <!-- Começo Plugin dos Correios Buscar Endereço pelo Cep -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>  
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>  
        <version>0.8.3</version>  
        <executions>  
          <execution>  
            <goals>  
              <goal>generate</goal>  
            </goals>  
         </execution>  
        </executions>  
     <configuration>  
        <generatePackage>br.com.correios.app</generatePackage>  
        <verbose>true</verbose>  
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>  
        <!-- <generateDirectory>src/main/java</generateDirectory>  -->  
       <schemas>  
        <schema>  
         <url>https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl</url>  
        </schema>  
       </schemas>  
     </configuration>  
    </plugin>
   <!-- Final Plugin dos Correios Buscar Endereço pelo Cep -->
```

como posso resolver isso grato a todos